# Facebook oauth using javascript for localhost website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I want to develop an app which support user to login with their facebook account.
Created an app in facebook.

[image]

noted down the app-id say xyzxyz123123.

created an htm file called fb.htm inside c:\inetpub\wwwroot

in fb.htm pasted code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/

replaced YOUR_APP_ID with xyzxyz123123.

I am getting following error.

[image]

What are all the changes do I need to do so that this will work?

Comment: _“What are all the changes do I need to do so that this will work?”_ – learning to _read_ would be a good start :-P Seriously, the error message already _tells_ you what’s wrong, so how hard is it to understand that and make the necessary adjustments in your app settings …?

Comment: I understand, but after read and try all possibilities whichever I know and from internet I'm not able to get it work. If you know the answer and if you ever tried, and if you suggest something instead of advice that will really help me a lot. :P

Comment: As Dominik already answered said, you have to set the URL of the site you want to use FB login on in the “Website with Facebook login” field. (Usually just the base address of the site is enough, it does not have to be a specific sub-page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to activate the mark "website with facebook login" and enter the right URL

Comment: for localhost website what url should I give over there?

And what is channel url? 

channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/02/how-to--optimize-social-plugin-performance/